# Why Jasper Chart Theme throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am testing `Chart Theme` with Jasper Report. Why I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I use `eye.candy.sixties` theme? Other themes is ok (eg : aegean, default,....)

BarChartTest.java

```
public class BarChartTest {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String templateFile = "resources/bar.jrxml";

        DataBeanList dataBeanList = new DataBeanList();
        ArrayList<DataBean> dataList = dataBeanList.getDataBeanList();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();

        try {
            JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(templateFile);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, beanColDataSource);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "D:/temp/bar_chart.pdf");  
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

bar.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jasper_report_template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="860" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="843cea12-1b23-4ff8-ae94-48b1850662ef">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="subjectName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="marks" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="countNumber" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="200">
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report" theme="eye.candy.sixties">
                    <reportElement uuid="5133611e-49a1-4e9a-b4e5-8eff4e29c61b" x="0" y="0" width="515" height="200"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <chartTitle position="Top">
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["My First JR Bar Chart"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{subjectName}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{subjectName}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{marks}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowTickMarks="false">
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

StackTrace

```
WARNING: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components
Sep 22, 2014 5:47:16 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment findBundles
WARNING: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components
Sep 22, 2014 5:47:16 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment findBundles
WARNING: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.chartthemes.spring.EyeCandySixtiesChartTheme.createBarChart(EyeCandySixtiesChartTheme.java:296)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.chartthemes.spring.GenericChartTheme.createChart(GenericChartTheme.java:266)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.evaluateChart(JRFillChart.java:844)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.evaluateRenderer(JRFillChart.java:809)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.resolveElement(JRFillChart.java:1385)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.performDelayedEvaluation(JRFillElement.java:983)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.resolveElement(JRFillElement.java:1085)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.ElementEvaluationAction.execute(JRBaseFiller.java:2486)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.resolveBoundElements(JRBaseFiller.java:1646)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.resolveReportBoundElements(JRBaseFiller.java:1673)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1087)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:329)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:159)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:892)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:984)
    at com.mutu.chart.test.BarChartTest.main(BarChartTest.java:34)
```

lib

```
jasperreports-chart-themes-4.0.2.jar
jasperreports-5.6.1.jar
jasperreports-applet-5.6.1.jar
jasperreports-fonts-5.6.1.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.1.jar
...other necessary jar files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a point why we get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when we use `eye.candy.sixties` theme.

Like my problem [Problem 1](http://community-static.jaspersoft.com/questions/821750/jasper-studio-chart-theme-eyecandysixties) [Problem 2](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530405/i-report-350-array-indexoutofboundsexception)

There is a following variable and method in `jasperreports-chart-themes-xxx.jar`. Main problem, `EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_GRADIENT_PAINTS` list size is seven.

In ChartThemesConstants.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static final List<GradientPaint> EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_GRADIENT_PAINTS = new ArrayList<GradientPaint>() {
    {
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(0), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(0)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(1), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(1)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(2), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(2)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(3), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(3)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(4), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(4)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(5), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(5)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(6), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(6)).darker()));
    }
};
```

In EyeCandySixtiesChartTheme.java

```
protected JFreeChart createBarChart() throws JRException {
    JFreeChart jfreeChart = super.createBarChart();

    CategoryPlot categoryPlot = (CategoryPlot) jfreeChart.getPlot();
    // categoryPlot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    BarRenderer barRenderer = (BarRenderer) categoryPlot.getRenderer();
    barRenderer.setItemMargin(0);
    barRenderer.setGradientPaintTransformer(new StandardGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformType.HORIZONTAL));
    CategoryDataset categoryDataset = categoryPlot.getDataset();
    if (categoryDataset != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryDataset.getRowCount(); i++) {
            barRenderer.setSeriesPaint(i, ChartThemesConstants.EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_GRADIENT_PAINTS.get(i));  <-- Here is point
        }
    }
    return jfreeChart;
}
```

When we use `categoryDataset`(x-axis data series) with size 8 and above,  we will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. 
In my project, `x-axis data series` might be over 10 and above. The solution is to re-write the `ChartThemesConstants.java` and create new jar file again.
I re-write as below and re-create new `jar`. Now, `x-axis data series` can use 20 data.

Re-Write ChartThemesConstants.java

```
....
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static final List<Color> EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS = new ArrayList<Color>() {
    {
        add(new Color(250, 97, 18));
        add(new Color(237, 38, 42));
        add(new Color(0, 111, 60));
        add(new Color(250, 223, 18));
        add(new Color(47, 137, 187));
        add(new Color(231, 133, 35));
        add(new Color(229, 1, 140));
        add(new Color(234, 171, 53));
        add(Color.decode("#F5F5DC"));
        add(Color.decode("#8B008B"));
        add(Color.decode("#556B2F"));
        add(Color.decode("#483D8B"));
        add(Color.decode("#ADFF2F"));
        add(Color.decode("#191970"));
        add(Color.decode("#9457EB"));
        add(Color.decode("#1A1110"));
        add(Color.decode("#F984E5"));
        add(Color.decode("#536878"));
        add(Color.decode("#32127A"));
        add(Color.decode("#80461B"));
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static final List<GradientPaint> EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_GRADIENT_PAINTS = new ArrayList<GradientPaint>() {
    {
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(0), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(0)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(1), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(1)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(2), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(2)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(3), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(3)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(4), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(4)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(5), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(5)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(6), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(6)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(7), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(7)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(8), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(8)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(9), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(9)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(10), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(10)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(11), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(11)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(12), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(12)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(13), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(13)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(14), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(14)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(15), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(15)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(16), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(16)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(17), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(17)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(18), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(18)).darker()));
        add(new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(19), 0f, 0f, (EYE_CANDY_SIXTIES_COLORS.get(19)).darker()));
    }
};
...
```